# Track AWS S3 bucket creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm working in an environment where anyone with the necessary access is allowed to create an S3 bucket; however, it's getting to a point where we have a lot of buckets and it is hard to keep track of who created the bucket. I know it is possible to tag the buckets with the owner name, but I am looking for a more automated solution.

Is it possible to invoke a lambda function every time a bucket is created? Or is it possible to track bucket creation with cloudtrail where system administrators would get an sns notification when an s3 bucket is created?

I know it is possible to configure s3 event notification inside a bucket to trigger lambda functions/cloudwatch metrics, but I need a trigger for the entire s3 application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloudtrail tracks all API Actions occurring within an account. What you want to do is create a cloudwatch event rule that triggers off the CreateBucket action then have it invoke Lambda or trigger a sns notification.

See: [Creating a CloudWatch Events Rule That Triggers on an AWS API Call Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use EventBridge to get at these events, via CloudTrail. The example on [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/event-types.html#events-for-services-not-listed) is of a `CreateBucket` request.